# Related content in Rails. User selects the content to relate. How to do? HasMany? BelongsTo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, many-to-many, has-many-through

The application have Posts, Products and Services. I want the user selects the specific content to relate. Example:

I have 2 services. And I'm adding a new PRODUCT. In this product, I want to relate these 2 services and other 1 product.

The first thing I thought is to create a field in the database like `related_content` in all resources and save the ids with comma, like it: `service_25, service_302, product_408`. I did it other times, and... works.

I save the prefix `service_` and `product_` because the same item can be related with products and services.

But I think it is not the right way. Perhaps the right way is to use the many to many association. But I don't know how to do.

## MODELS

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :menu_assigns, as: :menu_item, dependent: :destroy

    has_many :categorizings, as: :item, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :categories, -> { where for: Category.fors[:for_products] }, through: :categorizings

    has_one :attach, as: :attached, dependent: :destroy
    has_one :attachment, through: :attach
end
```

**service.rb**

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :menu_assigns, as: :menu_item, dependent: :destroy

    has_many :categorizings, as: :item, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :categories, -> { where for: Category.fors[:for_services] }, through: :categorizings

    has_one :attach, as: :attached, dependent: :destroy
    has_one :attachment, through: :attach
end
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :menu_assigns, as: :menu_item, dependent: :destroy

    has_many :categorizings, as: :item, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :categories, -> { where for: Category.fors[:for_posts] }, through: :categorizings

    has_one :attach, as: :attached, dependent: :destroy
    has_one :attachment, through: :attach
end
```

This code has already some associations:

**Menu:** Using menu_assigns, the user can add Post, Product and Service to menu.

**Category:** The resources has categories. Using categorizings, the content is related.

**Attachment:** Is the featured image. Using attach we relate an image.

But, how to relate each other using the associations?

I imagine something like it: `@page.related_content` and returns an object with the registers.

## My idea

1) Create a model called `related_groups` with these fields:

```
rails g model RelatedGroup item_id:integer item_type:string order:integer
```

Item ID is the ID of the related content. The item Type is the model (Product, Service, Post). The order field is the order to show.

2) In that model, create the relation:

```
class RelatedGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item, polymorphic: true
end
```

3) Do the relation in the resources (Product, Service, Post). Below the example to post:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :related_groups
end
```

4) Join the results in all models (Product, Service, Post). Below the example to post:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :related_groups
    with_options through: :related_groups, source: :item do
        has_many :posts, source_type: 'Post'
        has_many :products, source_type: 'Product'
        has_many :services, source_type: 'Service'
    end
end
```

This seems to be correct, but I'm not sure.

And the controllers? And the views?
In Post (example), how to create the checkboxes to check the related contents? And in the controller, how to save the data? And how to set the order?

I'm using `rails 4.2`

I appreciate any help. Tks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the has_and_belongs_to_many association:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many

Depending on your requirements you could either have one join table for each kind of related object (Post/Product/Service) or have a combined join table with an additional attribute to distinguish what kind of object you are associating with, e.g.

```
class CreatePostRelationJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :post_relations, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :post_id
      t.string  :relation_type
      t.integer :relation_id
    end
  end
end
```